# How to subtract values in a column using groupby

Tags: python, pandas, pandas-groupby

I have the following dataframe:

```
ID  Days TreatmentGiven TreatmentNumber
--- ---- -------------- ---------------
1    0      False             NaN
1    30     False             NaN
1    40     True               1
1    56     False             NaN 
2    0      False             NaN
2    14     True               1
2    28     True               2
```

I'd like to create a new column with a new baseline for Days based on when the first treatment was given (TreatmentNumber==1), grouped by ID so that the result is the following:

```
ID  Days TreatmentGiven TreatmentNumber New_Baseline
--- ---- -------------- --------------- ------------
1    0      False             NaN          -40
1    30     False             NaN          -10
1    40     True               1            0
1    56     False             NaN           16
2    0      False             NaN          -14
2    14     True               1            0
2    28     True               2            14
```

What is the best way to do this?

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is one approach with `series.where` + `groupby+transform`:

```
s = df['Days'].where(df['TreatmentGiven']).groupby(df['ID']).transform('first')
df['New_Baseline'] = df['Days'].sub(s)
```

---

Output

```
   ID  Days  TreatmentGiven  TreatmentNumber  New_Baseline
0   1     0           False              NaN         -40.0
1   1    30           False              NaN         -10.0
2   1    40            True              1.0           0.0
3   1    56           False              NaN          16.0
4   2     0           False              NaN         -14.0
5   2    14            True              1.0           0.0
6   2    28            True              2.0          14.0
```

Answer (score 2):

Idea is filter rows with `1` in `TreatmentNumber`, then convert to `Series` for [`Series.map`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.map.html) by `ID` used for subtract by `Days` column with [`Series.sub`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.sub.html):

```
s = df[df['TreatmentNumber'].eq(1)].set_index('ID')['Days']
#Series created by first True rows by TreatmentGiven per groups
#s = df[df['TreatmentGiven']].drop_duplicates('ID').set_index('ID')['Days']
df['New_Baseline'] = df['Days'].sub(df['ID'].map(s))
print (df)
   ID  Days  TreatmentGiven  TreatmentNumber  New_Baseline
0   1     0           False              NaN           -40
1   1    30           False              NaN           -10
2   1    40            True              1.0             0
3   1    56           False              NaN            16
4   2     0           False              NaN           -14
5   2    14            True              1.0             0
6   2    28            True              2.0            14
```

**Detail**:

```
print (s)
ID
1    40
2    14
Name: Days, dtype: int64

print (df['ID'].map(s))
0    40
1    40
2    40
3    40
4    14
5    14
6    14
Name: ID, dtype: int64
```

Answer (score 1):

This is anoher approach:

```
aux = df[df['TreatmentGiven']==True].groupby('ID')['Days'].first().reset_index()

df = df.merge(aux,how='left',on='ID').rename(columns={'Days_x':'Days','Days_y':'New_baseline'})
df['New_baseline'] = df['Days'] - df['New_baseline']
```

Output:

```
     ID Days    TreatmentGiven  TreatMentNumber New_baseline
 0    1    0             False              NaN          -40
 1    1   30             False              NaN          -10
 2    1   40              True              1.0            0
 3    1   56             False              NaN           16
 4    2    0             False              NaN          -14
 5    2   14              True              1.0            0
 6    2   28              True              2.0           14
```